# How to strengthen and make better use of a weak pinky finger on the violin?

Tags: practice, violin, fingering

I've always had a weak pinky finger, which has bothered me quite often. Actually, it is too long to fit comfortably and properly on several occasions. However, I treated each case specifically with several tricks. Now, I feel that my pinky is almost always out of position, it is like a "dead" finger and, moreover, it feels uncomfortable even in extension, where, in general, I had no problem in extensions, specifically.

So, I would like some advice on both giving a more active role to my pinky, since, quite often I prefer changing position to, for instance, play a trill, than play it with my pinky, and also on making it more comfortable in cases were extension is needed, since it would be nice to be able to exploit at least the length of my fingers.

Comment: My number one suggestion is just use it a lot. The exercises posted below by Jomiddnz should  do wonders if done consistently for several weeks/months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not many violinists would use their pinky to trill with by choice, unless the context requires it.  It is natural to change position to a stronger finger for trills.  Your pinky (like most people's) is weaker than the other three fingers.  It therefore needs more exercise.  Take a look at these: